# Mining pools overseas and the impact on the hashrate

Tags: mining-pools, monero-network-hashrate

I am located in USA but I am mining using a pool in France. The question is, because the pool is overseas does it impact my hashrate ?

I noticed a week ago I was about 1.8-2 KH/s and now I have a miserable 1.3KH/s.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what miner you are using, but if you're using XMR-Stak, one of the better ones at the moment, you can click 'r' to get a report on your submitted work. If you have a low acceptance rate, you are losing your work.

Here's an example from one of my own workers that runs through an SSH tunnel (which adds latency).

```
RESULT REPORT
Difficulty       : 18000
Good results     : 9233 / 9284 (99.5 %)
Avg result time  : 105.2 sec
Pool-side hashes : 45846000

Top 10 best results found:
|  0 |         62213495 |  1 |         54395912 |
|  2 |         28981579 |  3 |         28899680 |
|  4 |         28802304 |  5 |         26687670 |
|  6 |         23322195 |  7 |         16208637 |
|  8 |         15118120 |  9 |         13861144 |

Error details:
| Count | Error text                       | Last seen           |
|     9 | Low difficulty share             | 2017-06-19 15:55:14 |
|    11 | [NETWORK ERROR]                  | 2017-06-18 15:01:07 |
|    31 | Block expired                    | 2017-06-21 07:07:45 |
```

As you can see, my "good rate" is 99.5%. This is on a slow CPU which also does a lot of other work and often has CPU power taken away for other tasks.

I've noticed that the hashrate reported by the pools vary a fair bit, so I'm not sure they can be trusted. I calculate my own hashrate by polling the pool API and averaging over 1 hour. I can then compare that to the sum of rates reported by each worker. ('h' key in XMR-Stak.)

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not affect your hashrate however you may be submitting invalid shares due to high latency I would recommend switching to a closer pool to avoid invalid share which can result in penalties.

Comment: thank you! do you have any recommendation in terms of pool in USA ?

Comment: I don't really know the power of your mining system you should calculate your earnings and look at minimum payouts from pools you are considering to make sure you can get paid in a reasonable period of time. I would look at http://www.moneropools.com/ to find a good pool under the USA or Global section. Also consider said pools fees/donations and their total hashrate to look at how often you will get paid. maybe consider https://monerohash.com/. I've never mined with them nor have any connection to them but their hashrate looks reasonable and you can request a payout below the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect your hardware hashrate, but it could have an impact on your effective hashrate - which is what the pool sees and reports to you. It can't tell what your hardware is doing, but has to estimate it based on how often you submit solved shares for a given difficulty.

When you're mining, you receive a share, run your hardware until you find a solution and submit the solution to the pool who then gives you another share. Now, what does your hardware do during the time the solution is being transmitted to the pool or during the time it's waiting for new work?
 Nothing.

So, you'd want to minimize this wasted time. You can do some things:

- pick a closer pool, to reduce the time wasted on transmissions
- pick a bigger difficulty to mine at, to reduce the number of times you have to waste time. Here you have to experiment a bit. If you go too high, you might have dropped shares, if you go too low you might be wasting too much time on communicating with the pool. Try a setting where you find a share each 15s or so and see how it works out